# Unable to disable button in ag-grid

Tags: angular, button, ag-grid, ag-grid-angular

I want to disable a button in a column using the click event of a button in another column in ag-grid.

I have used common service to disable it, but it disabled all the buttons in that column and I've also tried updating that column's field in params object(rowData), but didn't work.

Here is a sample on [stackbltiz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-lvratr?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

Edit: Added source code

app.component.html

```html
<h1>Hello World</h1>

<ag-grid-angular
  style="width: 500px; height: 350px;"
  class="ag-theme-alpine"
  [rowData]="rowData"
  [columnDefs]="columnDefs"
>
</ag-grid-angular>
```

app.component.ts

```js
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { ColDef } from 'ag-grid-community';
import { ButtonRendererComponent } from './button-renderer/button-renderer.component';
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css'],
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
})
export class AppComponent {
  columnDefs: ColDef[] = [
    {
      field: 'make',
      headerName: 'Button1',
      cellRenderer: ButtonRendererComponent,
      cellRendererParams: {
        comp: 'label1',
      },
    },
    {
      field: 'model',
      headerName: 'Button1',
      cellRenderer: ButtonRendererComponent,
      cellRendererParams: {
        comp: 'label2',
      },
    },
    { field: 'price' },
  ];

  rowData = [
    {
      make: 'Toyota',
      model: 'Celica',
      price: 35000,
      button1: true,
      button2: false,
    },
    {
      make: 'Ford',
      model: 'Mondeo',
      price: 32000,
      button1: true, //fetched from DB
      button2: false, //fetched from DB
    },
    {
      make: 'Porsche',
      model: 'Boxster',
      price: 72000,
      button1: true, //fetched from DB
      button2: false, //fetched from DB
    },
  ];
}
```

button-renderer.component.html

```html
<button
  *ngIf="params['comp'] == 'label1'"
  mat-flat-button
  color="primary"
  (click)="clickButton1()"
  [disabled]="isButton1Disabled"
>
  Button1
</button>
<button
  *ngIf="params['comp'] == 'label2'"
  mat-flat-button
  color="primary"
  (click)="clickButton2()"
  [disabled]="comSvc.isButtonDisabled"
>
  Button2
</button>
```

button-renderer.component.ts

```js
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ICellRendererAngularComp } from 'ag-grid-angular';
import { ICellRendererParams } from 'ag-grid-community';
import { CommonService } from '../common.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-button-renderer',
  templateUrl: './button-renderer.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./button-renderer.component.css'],
})
export class ButtonRendererComponent implements ICellRendererAngularComp {
  params: any;
  isButton1Disabled: boolean = false;
  isButton2Disabled: boolean = true;
  agInit(params: ICellRendererParams): void {
    this.params = params;
  }

  // gets called whenever the cell refreshes
  refresh(params: ICellRendererParams): boolean {
    // set value into cell again
    return true;
  }
  constructor(public comSvc: CommonService) {}

  ngOnInit() {}
  clickButton1() {
    console.log('Button 1 is clicked');
    // this.isButton2Disabled = true;
    // this.params.button2 = true;
    this.comSvc.isButtonDisabled = true;
    //DB update call
  }
  clickButton2() {
    console.log('Button 2 is clicked');
    //DB update call
  }
}
```

Packages:

```
Angular: 16.2.0 
ag-grid-angular: 30.2.0
```

Comment: Welcome to SO, Please post your code instead of a stackblitz link.

Comment: @JFPicard Added source code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is normal to disable every buttons with you current code, as the service is common for every components and you have only one state for the button. This means all buttons have the same disabled state.

### Solution 1: Use a service keeping all row disabled states

A solution is to keep your service and have a map of id rows and disabled state

cell renderer component html:

```html
<button *ngIf="params['comp'] == 'label1'" mat-flat-button color="primary" (click)="clickButton1()">
  Button1
</button>
<button *ngIf="params['comp'] == 'label2'" mat-flat-button color="primary" (click)="clickButton2()" [disabled]="comSvc.isDisabled(this.params.rowIndex)">
  Button2
</button>
```

cell renderer component ts:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ICellRendererAngularComp } from 'ag-grid-angular';
import { ICellRendererParams } from 'ag-grid-community';
import { CommonService } from '../common.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-button-renderer',
  templateUrl: './button-renderer.component.html',
})
export class ButtonRendererComponent implements ICellRendererAngularComp {
  params: any;

  agInit(params: ICellRendererParams): void {
    this.params = params;
  }

  // gets called whenever the cell refreshes
  refresh(params: ICellRendererParams): boolean {
    // set value into cell again
    return true;
  }

  constructor(public comSvc: CommonService) {}

  clickButton1() {
    console.log(`Button 1 is clicked on row index${this.params.rowIndex}`);
    this.comSvc.disableButtonOnRow(this.params.rowIndex);
    //DB update call
  }
  clickButton2() {
    console.log('Button 2 is clicked');
    //DB update call
  }
}
```

the service:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable()
export class CommonService {
  private disabledButtonByRow = new Map<number, boolean>();

  public disableButtonOnRow(rowId: number): void {
    this.disabledButtonByRow.set(rowId, true);
  }

  public isDisabled(rowId: number): boolean {
    console.log('is disabled is called!' + rowId);
    return !!(
      this.disabledButtonByRow.has(rowId) && this.disabledButtonByRow.get(rowId)
    );
  }
}
```

### Solution 2: Put both buttons in the same cell renderer

Why is there 2 buttons in one cell renderer component with a if, when you share no logic between them and only display one.
Things get way easier when you display both buttons in one cell as you can share the logic.

cell renderer component html:

```html
<button mat-flat-button color="primary" (click)="clickButton1()">
  Button1
</button>
<button mat-flat-button color="primary" (click)="clickButton2()" [disabled]="button2DisabledState">
  Button2
</button>
```

cell renderer component ts:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { ICellRendererAngularComp } from 'ag-grid-angular';
import { ICellRendererParams } from 'ag-grid-community';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-button-renderer',
  templateUrl: './button-renderer.component.html',
})
export class ButtonRendererComponent implements ICellRendererAngularComp {
  button2DisabledState= false;

  agInit(): void {
  }

  // gets called whenever the cell refreshes
  refresh(params: ICellRendererParams): boolean {
    // set value into cell again
    return false;
  }

  clickButton1() {
    this.button2DisabledState= true;
    //DB update call
  }
  clickButton2() {
    console.log('Button 2 is clicked');
    //DB update call
  }
}
```

table component ts:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { ColDef } from 'ag-grid-community';
import { ButtonRendererComponent } from './button-renderer/button-renderer.component';
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css'],
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
})
export class AppComponent {
  columnDefs: ColDef[] = [
    {
      field: 'make',
      headerName: 'Button1 & 2',
      cellRenderer: ButtonRendererComponent,
      flex:2
    },
    { field: 'price',
      flex: 1 
    },
  ];

  rowData = [
    {
      make: 'Toyota',
      model: 'Celica',
      price: 35000,
      button1: true,
      button2: false,
    },
    {
      make: 'Ford',
      model: 'Mondeo',
      price: 32000,
      button1: true, //fetched from DB
      button2: false, //fetched from DB
    },
    {
      make: 'Porsche',
      model: 'Boxster',
      price: 72000,
      button1: true, //fetched from DB
      button2: false, //fetched from DB
    },
  ];
}
```

### Solution 3: Update row data to refresh the cell renderers

cell renderer component html:

```html
<button
  mat-flat-button
  color="primary"
  (click)="params.actionOnClick()"
  [disabled]="params.value"
>
  {{params.buttonName}}
</button>
```

cell renderer component ts:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ICellRendererAngularComp } from 'ag-grid-angular';
import { ICellRendererParams } from 'ag-grid-community';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-button-renderer',
  templateUrl: './button-renderer.component.html',
})
export class ButtonRendererComponent implements ICellRendererAngularComp {
  params: any;

  agInit(params: ICellRendererParams): void {
    this.params = params;
  }

  // gets called whenever the cell refreshes
  refresh(params: ICellRendererParams): boolean {
    // set value into cell again
    return false;
  }
}
```

table component ts:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { ColDef } from 'ag-grid-community';
import { ButtonRendererComponent } from './button-renderer/button-renderer.component';
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css'],
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
})
export class AppComponent {
  columnDefs: ColDef[] = [
    {
      field: 'button1',
      headerName: 'Button1',
      cellRenderer: ButtonRendererComponent,
      cellRendererParams: (params: any) => ({
        buttonName: 'Button 1',
        actionOnClick: () => {
          console.log(`Button 1 is clicked on row index${params.rowIndex}`);
          this.rowData[params.rowIndex].button2 = true;
          // force aggrid to detect changes in row Data
          this.rowData = [...this.rowData];
        },
      }),
    },
    {
      field: 'button2',
      headerName: 'Button2',
      cellRenderer: ButtonRendererComponent,
      cellRendererParams: {
        buttonName: 'Button 2',
        actionOnClick: () => {
          console.log('Button 2 is clicked');
          //DB update call
        },
      },
    },
    { field: 'price' },
  ];

  rowData = [
    {
      make: 'Toyota',
      model: 'Celica',
      price: 35000,
      button1: false,
      button2: false,
    },
    {
      make: 'Ford',
      model: 'Mondeo',
      price: 32000,
      button1: false, //fetched from DB
      button2: false, //fetched from DB
    },
    {
      make: 'Porsche',
      model: 'Boxster',
      price: 72000,
      button1: true, //fetched from DB
      button2: false, //fetched from DB
    },
  ];
}
```

The important part here, is `this.rowData = [...this.rowData];`, which helps aggrid to detect changes in the rowData

Comment: Thanks, I tried all of them and solution 1 seems to work for me. 

Buttons need to be in separate columns as headerName and functionality of each button is different. Once the buttons are clicked, record in DB is updated.

Comment: The issue with this solution is that `comSvc.isDisabled(this.params.rowIndex)` is called a lot of times (at each angular change, even when nothing is touched) due to `[disabled]="comSvc.isDisabled(this.params.rowIndex)"` in the html

Comment: Yes, I observed that too. The thing is button1 is dependent on other cell editors that I'm using in the actual project.

Comment: Are you trying to do a form with controls in aggrid? IMO it's a pain in the ass and should be avoided. It's easier to open a pop up when clicking on an edit,button/icon and deal with a real form, material inputs and submit button. This is better for input validation too and for readability

Comment: I suugested a popup too, but the client asked for inline editing. So I went with cellEditors. Anyways, the current architecture has been revisited and entirely migrated to the one with material inputs and form contol

Comment: an other way is to do line editing on row, replacing aggrid, by simple html table & td. This removes aggrid abilities as cell grouping/filtering options but allows line editing and gives easy access to form and data